# Sparse matrix CRS logic for IA array

Tags: algorithm, matrix, sparse-matrix

I tried realise `Sparse matrix`  storage format. Wikipedia say: [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix)

I need `CRS` algoritm. But I can not understand the algorithm to the end. I have matrix like in example in link

```
0 0 0 0
5 8 0 0
0 0 3 0 
0 6 0 0
```

and 3 arrays

```
   A  = [ 5 8 3 6 ]
   IA = [ 0 0 2 3 4 ]
   JA = [ 0 1 2 1 ]
```

Ok I understand, what A - all not zero elements
                      JA - column index of first not zero element in row
                      But by what logic is IA???

Answer (score 0):

The `AI[]` vector stores the locations that **start a row**.

For instance all the non zero elements of row `i` have their values stored in `A[k]` and their assocated j-indices in `AJ[k]` where `k` is such that

`AI[i] <= k <= AI[i+1]-1`

**The central idea to grasp is contained in the next two lines:**

`AI[i]`: is the offset to jump at the beginning of the `row i`

`AI[i+1]-1`: is the offset to jump at the beginning of the `row i+1`, **but** as we remove **1** this becomes the **last element** of `row i`

---

To illustrate this we can compute a matrix-vector product, y=A.x, in the 2 cases: dense and CRS format (pseudo code):

When A is dense, we have:

```
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)       // row i
  {
      y[i] = 0;

      for (j = 0; j < N; j++)   // column j
          y[i] += A[i][j] * x[j];         
  }
```

to be compared to case where A is stored using the CRS format:

```
   for (i = 0; i < N; i++)   // row i
   {  
      y[i]=0;

      for (k = AI[i]; k < AI[i+1]; k++) // nonzero element of row i
      {  
         y[i] += A[k] * x[AJ[k]];
      }  
   }
```